# all unoriented bordism groups are $\mathbb{Z}/2$s

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, cobordism

Is it true that all unoriented bordism groups are $\mathbb{Z}/2$ vector spaces?

This means that any unoriented bordism groups must be of the form:
$$
\mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus  \mathbb{Z}/2  \dots?
$$

1. If so what is the precise proof for this? My way of seeing it is that
   two of $M$ bound $M\times I_1$ if we do not have orientations. Namely
   $$
   \partial(M\times I_1) = M \sqcup M
   $$
   So two of $M$ as M \sqcup M must be trivial null bordant. Is this precise and no loop hole rigorous?
2. However, unoriented bordism groups with spin structures such as $pin^+$ and $pin^-$ can have more than $\mathbb{Z}/2$ classes? How do we understand it? Since
   $$
   \Omega_2^{pin^-}=\mathbb{Z}/8.
   $$
   What is wrong with my argument in the item 1 to show that $\Omega_2^{pin^-}$ must be $\mathbb{Z}/2^k$?

Comment: You might benefit from http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Unoriented_bordism and references therein.

Comment: thanks could you share more insights? I knew that note... beforehand